# ORACLE BUSQUEDA DE DATOS

Tags: plsql

alguien conoce alguna manera de buscar palabras dentro del oracle developer??? para que busque coinicidencias dentro de la base de datos
nesecito encontrar en donde podrian hacer SELECTS a una tabla las funciones o procedimientos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias intentar algo asi:

select * from **NOMBRE_TABLA** where **CAMPO_DE_BUSQUEDA** like '%**LO_QUE_QUIERES_BUSCAR**%';

o si quieres buscar alguna palabra dentro de la Query es con **ctrl + f**

Comment: muchas gracias :3